# How to open mail panel in Swift? Mac OS

Tags: swift, macos, email, messageui

For the past few days I've been strugling with finding a way to send emails from my app. This is the sample code I am currently using. It think, by using this method, I might be unable to handle the situation of an improper setting of the mail accound of the computer my app will be running, so I thought about using a different method.  I was wondering if is there any MessageUI equivalent for mac os. Is there any MessageUI equivalent for mac os. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

1. `AppleScript` framework
2. `NSSharingService`

**NSSharingService to compose mail:**

```
let service = NSSharingService(named: NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail)

service?.recipients = ["test@gmail.com"]
service?.subject = "Test Mail"
service?.performWithItems(["Test Mail body"])
```

**Launch Mail App**

If you just want to open `Mail` app, try below code:

```
NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().launchApplication("Mail")
```

**Improper Setting:**

- If account is not configured on the system, this code will show configuration window for mail
- When user will try to send mail it'll be shown improper setting related error by Mail app so you need not to bother about it
- If you want to use other then Mail app, just try your own mail system, native mail client or third party mail framework.

**Try from terminal:**

You can use shell script to send mail using native client

```
mail -s "Hello" "test@gmail.com" <<EOF
Hello, Test!
EOF
```

Comment: managed to figure it out before having the chance to update my question, but still thank you and great answer!

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 4, little changes.

```
let service = NSSharingService(named: NSSharingService.Name.composeEmail)
service?.recipients = ["test@gmail.com"]
service?.subject = "Test Mail"
service?.perform(withItems: ["Test Mail body"])
```